# CSS stylesheets being override even it is in last sequence

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, vertical-alignment

Here is some code of my main jsp file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/styles/bootstrap.min'/>,bootstrap-switch.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<c:url value='/styles/main.css'/>"/>
```

The `main.css` is at the line after `bootstrap css`, so usually, `main.css` will override the `bootstrap css`. (correct me if I am wrong.)

Inside `main.css`, I have create 1 class as follow:

```
.testjx{
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And here is my sub jsp file:

```
<td class="testjx">
     1000000
</td>
```

When I view the page in browser, I found that `vertical-align:middle` is override by `bootstrap css` file, as follow screen shot:

[image]

I try my best to find out the root cause, but fail. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do like this:

```
table tr td.testjx, table tfoot tr td.testjx, table thead tr td.testjx, table tbody tr td.testjx{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

> You need to inspect where the class is to short the css code...check
>   if is on the tfoot, thead or tbody or general

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cdna8aqb/6/)**

Comment: But I want to apply to 1 `td` only. This will apply to whole `td` in the table right? Or do you means that set css class in td will no have any effect on some attribute like `vertical-align` ?

Comment: This css code will only affect the `td` width class `.testjx`

Comment: use table tr td:nth-child(n) .testjx{ vertical-align:middle;} in which td you wants to apply

Comment: Actually I just want to apply to only 1 `td` , I have a lot of `td` in 1 row, but I only want to apply for 1 `td` only. If I put in `.testjx tbody tr td `, whole my td will affected, and become yelllow color.

Comment: Opps~ Sory, too blur as my eye keep see on code. Just found that my code is actually different with yours, at first I thought is the same, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this by adding `!important` to the relevant CSS i.e. `font-weight:bold !important;` and this stops it being overridden regardless of which file it's in. Simples.

Comment: I used font-weight as an example, I know you're looking at vertical-align but the principle still applies.